# Do these singularities of $\boldsymbol{f(z)}$ lie within the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, circles, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I want to evaluate an integral in terms of its parametersAfter applying the change of variables ($d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$) to a trigonometric function with paraemters a,b,c, originally evaluated over $[0,2\pi]$, I obtain the following integral where k is the unit circle:

$I=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta+c} d\theta = 2 \oint \frac{1}{a(\frac{z+z^-1}{2})+b(\frac{z-z^-1}{2i})+c} dz = 2 \oint_{k_{(0,1)}} \frac{1}{(ai+b)z^2+(2ic)z+(ai-b)} dz$.

Now, the singularities of f(z) will occur when the denominator = $0$. So next I solved the quadratic to find its root and therefore the singularities of f(z).

I want to use the residue formula for simple poles. I have identified the possible singularities as: $\alpha=\frac{-ci \pm i\sqrt{c^2-a^2-b^2}}{ai+b}$. I know I must now identify which, if any, of the roots lie within the unit circle so I know which ones to calulcate their residue at, and then followed by the value of the integral.

How can I identify where these roots lie, perhaps using modulus arguments, and the fact that I have also identifed the original integral to converge for $|a|+|b|<|c|$?

Comment: Also I have started with assuming three cases: either $a<b, a>b and a=b$ as this will have different cases for the value of the integral, and determine if they lie inside the circle. If they both do, the integral value is 0.

Comment: Where does the equality$$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta+c}\,\mathrm d\theta = 2 \oint \frac{1}{a(\frac{z+z^-1}{2})+b(\frac{z-z^-1}{2i})+c}\,\mathrm dz$$come from?

Comment: Using $z=e^{i\theta}$ and the identities $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ and $sin\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$, and $\frac{dz}{d\theta}=ie^{i\theta} \Rightarrow \d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$. The final integral is after simplifying so a quadratic is on the denominator, with factors taken outside/ cancelled out.

Comment: What you should have obtained was$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta+c}\,\mathrm d\theta=-i\oint\frac1{z\left(a\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}2\right)+b\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)+c\right)}\,\mathrm dz.$$

Comment: I've just checked it but i'm not sure where my mistake is? I do:

Initial substitutions: $I = \oint \frac{1}{(a[\frac{z+z^-1}{2}]+b[\frac{z-z^-1}{2i}+c)} \frac{dz}{iz}$

Taking$ \frac{1}{i}$ out as factor=$I = \frac{1}{i} \oint \frac{1}{(a[\frac{z+z^-1}{2}]+b[\frac{z-z^-1}{2i}+c)} \frac{dz}{z}. $

Multiply by $\frac{1}{z}$ = $\oint \frac{1}{(\frac{az^2+a}{2}]+\frac{bz^2-b}{2i}+cz)} dz$

Make common denomintor of $2i$ (for fractions involving 2 and 2i). Take this factor outside and the $\frac{1}{i} $and $2i$ reduce to just 2?

Comment: Start with the RHS of the equality of my previous comment, apply the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $\mathrm dz=ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta$, and you will obtaint the LHS.

Comment: Doing so I am left with the original integral yes, but not $I$, $-I$ instead?

Comment: When you multiply the $i$ from $ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta$ with the $-i$ to the left of $\oint$, you get $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: Of course how silly of me - a case of tunnel vision i think. Thank you very much for your replies. Im going to reavlaute what ive done and try to analyse what conditions result in the roots lying within the unit circle

Comment: After multiplying the brackets out, you end up with the same same integral I stated before, with the same quadratic on the denominator with a factor of 2 outside the integral:

$-i \oint \frac{1}{z[a(\frac{z+z^-1}{2}+b(\frac{z-z^-1}{2i})+c]} dz$

=$ -i \oint \frac{2i}{aiz^2+ai+bz^2-b+2ciz}$

The 2i and -i reduce to 2.